# Rest api for create room on hangouts chat

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-hangouts

I have required to create room on hangouts chat via API request. But could not found any API end point for this. Could any one help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there doesn't appear to be a programmatic way to create a room. This is a likely due to the fact that having a script or bot that could create rooms could potentially spam room creation (whether intentionally or unintentionally). It's possible this could change in the future (likely with some limitations), but nothing has been confirmed by Google yet. Right now rooms can only be created manually through the UI.

Of course, you can always submit a feature request to their issue tracker [found here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:350158%2B). I recommend checking first if a this feature request has already been submitted by someone else and then commenting and upvoting that as it would receive more visibility. If not, you can [create a new one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215) and explain your use case.